# Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink. Ubuntu 18.10 >19.01

Tags: python3, symbolic-link

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 but I'm getting the error

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.

I tried different options from this portal but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be much appreciate it.

Comment: How did you *release-upgrade*?   It sounds to me like you tried to upgrade as if using *Debian* and not tested & supported Ubuntu tools built for that purpose.  *Ubuntu releases occur more regularly & rely on python, so deal with python more strictly through timing...*

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained exactly what you tried, and the details of each resulting error. "I tried different options" is a bit too vague to be useful. Please also clearly explain all change you made to the original system-installed Python3.

Comment: Maybe useful:   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  Ubuntu 18.10 was only tested to *release-upgrade* to 19.04 which reaches EOL itself on Thursday (23-Jan-2020) so you've left little time..

Comment: I tried these commands:
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6.8 2
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
do-release-upgrade

I'm still getting the same error:
extracting 'disco.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Cannot upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink. 

Any help there?